# Can a node reconnect to a network without boot nodes

Tags: networking, peers, libp2p

Is it possible to configure a full node to remember a list of last peers it connected to so when it restarts it doesn't need to rely on boot nodes to connect successfully to the chain network?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently implemented in Substrate however there is an open issue: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4750